# Do all windows based programs use the windows API? How are programs made without it?

Tags: windows, api, dll, assembly, operating-system

I've been programming for a few years, and I know how to create my own complex methods using pre-existing/standard libraries. I was always wondering (Java for example) how is a JFrame created when creating a JFrame object in Java? How do you use standard code (no libraries) to code a GUI or complex operations like creating files, reading files, etc.

If all these existing methods we use can be compared to building blocks we use to build a pyramid. How are these blocks created in the first place? (I mean technically). A programming language without standard libraries is variables, loops, and math (and even the math functions were created by someone).

The basic question is Does Java or C or any other language (while operating on Windows for example) complete all its operations by calling Windows .dll libraries for creating windows and other complex operations?

If so, How were these complex operations/methods/functions created in an operating system with just regular variables, loops, etc.

There's a gap in my understanding of programming.
I understand computers read binary (electricity = on/off), someone made assembly/assembler to convert binary to more readable code which moves numbers from different registers in a processor, which can lead to basic math, addition, subtraction, multiplication, divison. The gap in my understanding is the jump from Assembly to a higher language like C that holds variables, does loops, creates GUIS, Operating systems.

Comment: This kind of question is off topic on SO because of its breadth and scope and will most likely be closed soon. But, I would suggest studying the GTK  project which should shed some light on UIs between different platforms and languages: http://www.gtk.org/

Comment: The interface from assembly code to a high level language code is quite simple. In assembly, you can write a function that's callable from a HLL. The linker does the rest. From a HLL perspective, it's just an function that's defined in some other file.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  All normal Win32 applications use Windows DLL libraries to perform all operations such as displaying windows and accessing files.  (How Windows itself works is too big a question to answer here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to state the connection here (very)roughly AFAIK

- **hardware** = they can do things actually if instructed in their language i.e. streams of 1 and 0 in the form of electrical pulses (voltage high/low);
- **bus/network** = supplies/carries those electric pulses
- **Control Unit** = an important piece of hardware residing in CPU controls the buses to route the signal/pulses
- **instructions(machine code)** = stream of 1 and 0 that the control unit can understand; this is predetermined by who manufactures it; this can tell the control unit how to work with CPU registers, memory and I/O devices(i.e. computer hardware)
- **process** = set of instructions residing in memory
- **operating system** = set of processes giving access to hardware, new processes can be created with system calls to existing processes. Syscalls are human readable instructions ultimately being converted into machine code
- **object file/binary file/executables** = when a process is not in memory and not executing but residing in disk; CPU instructs BIOS to look for OS loaders, bootloaders starts a mother process to start the OS and that mother process generates other processes from (kernel)object files residing in disks
- **assembler** = produces object code(file) from assembly code; assembly code is the immediate human readable form of instructions doing all those storing, loading in CPU registers and memory, writing/signalling to various I/O devices
- **compiler/interpreters etc.** = converts more higher level languages to instructions ultimately(variables are stored in memory, loops are converted into jumps from one location in memory to another, if you are interested look at the assembly code generated from simple C programs with `gcc -S source.c -o assembly.s`)
- **program(source code)** = a language both human and compiler understands
- **driver** = programs which are used to communicate with hardware, they produce such object codes which contain the instructions necessary to deal with a particular piece of hardware; a proprietary hardware won't reveal it's instructions so you have to download their binaries
- **library/API** = piece of object codes/compiler understandable codes stored on disk so you don't need to reinvent the wheel every time you write a program

So, when you are creating a GUI from Java it's actually requesting your window manager to create the GUI in the form "*draw a 20x20 rectangle with corners rounded with radius 5px*" by it's native method calls, window manager is forwarding this request to OS processes which, via drivers, forwarding appropriate instructions to Control Unit, then the mighty CU will send some signal to your monitor to colour the appropriate pixels to give you a feeling of GUI.

<sub>I know I'll get many downvotes for answering like a simpleton and to a reported off-topic question :P</sub>

Comment: Even so, it was a nice explanation.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is really broad and generic, but I believe that the answer involves an understanding of the role of an operating system. Programs cannot do anything that the operating system does not allow them to do, and there is always a defined interface to the operating system from the program's perspective. This interface may be really low level, as in system calls via interrupts, or it may be at a higher level as in the Win32 API. Alot of this has to do also with hardware and drivers, since you cannot have input and output to a program without hardware, which is abstracted from the end program via the operating system. As an example, nVidia provides windows drivers which are abstracted by a number of APIs: OpenGL, DirectX, WPF, etc; if you knew the low level access to the video card drivers via system calls you could write your own API. Any language, such as Java or C, has to use these interfaces.

I hope that helps...